# Applying @Scheduled to@Cacheable rest method

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am trying to add a schedule to a rest get method, The scheduler works fine when I use it without the @Cacheable annotation. Like so -

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000*5)
@GetMapping("test")
public void test(){
    System.out.println("scheduled task through spring");
}
```

The problem is, when I add the @Cacheable annotation, the request is loaded once, and then the scheduler doesn't repeat.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000*5)
@Cacheable("testData")
@GetMapping("test")
public void test(){
   System.out.println("scheduled task through spring");
}
```

I have googled around, but I can only find information on @CacheEvict with @Scheduled

Comment: What is your goal on this? It would make more sense to put @Cacheable on a method that your controller would call (service class method).

Comment: The real method calls from a database, I want to store the information in Cache and refresh the cache every x amount of time

Comment: This method wont be refreshing cache. Cacheable itself isn't refreshing any data. A method annotated with Cacheable will try to take items from cache every time. If you want to refresh cache, you should rather use a fixed delay scheduling on a CacheEvict or CachePut method, OR set up cache management, so that entries would be held for maximum X amount of time.

Comment: Ok, great! I will give it a go. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe putting `@Cacheable` on a `void` method makes sense. Even if the method was returning a value...

I believe `@Scheduled` is firing, but `@Cacheable` is causing the cached value to be returned, instead of executing the method again. I think that makes sense.

Turn on DEBUG logging to verify.

Good luck!

Comment: The method I am using does return a value, this was just to show what I am working with and what I am trying to acheive